# How to get attachment of EmailMessage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, exchange-server

I try to get images which you can find in the Attachment of an EmailMessage. But when I run the code I'm getting this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is the code:

```
string sHTMLCOntent = item.Body;

FileAttachment[] attachments = null;

if (item.Attachments.Count != 0)
{
    attachments = new FileAttachment[item.Attachments.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Attachments.Count; i++)
    {
        string sType = item.Attachments[i].ContentType.ToLower();
        if (sType.Contains("image"))
        {
            attachments[i] = (FileAttachment)item.Attachments[i];
            string sID = attachments[i].ContentId;
            sType = sType.Replace("image/", "");
            string sFilename = sID + "." + sType;
            string sPathPlusFilename = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + sFilename;
            attachments[i].Load(sFilename);
            string oldString = "cid:" + sID;
            sHTMLCOntent = sHTMLCOntent.Replace(oldString, sPathPlusFilename);
        }
    }
}
//string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(item.MimeContent.Content);
//FreeTextBox1.Text += s;
```

Comment: error should also give you a line number.

Comment: Line 88:                             string sType = item.Attachments[i].ContentType.ToLower();

Comment: Then either `item`, `Attachments[i]` or `ContentType` are null, probably `Attachments[i]`.

Comment: what is the type of the EmailMessage object you refer to.  what namespace is it in?

Comment: using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data; 
item is an EmailMessage object

Comment: Step through the code with the debugger and check your objects. You will find that one of them are null, which means you cannot call methods on it. And when you do find the object that is null, write a guard against the null case so that you don't throw NullRefs. If you need support in your coding, try Resharper as it usually tells you where you have unguarded NullRef cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are blowing up on

```
string sType = item.Attachments[i].ContentType.ToLower();
```

and you have already checked the lengh of the Attachments, then the content type of the [Attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.transport.email.attachment_members%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx) object must not be set.  Since you are using this to perform the rest of your code, looks like this is required for you.  How is this message being generated?

I would add some code to take a look at the attachment, maybe the AttachmentType or FileName property, to ensure you have the attachment details, and determine the course of action.  Maybe you are adding the attachment yourself and just need to set the contenttype.  Good luck!

Comment: updated with Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Email Namespace.  The same logic applies though for either namespace

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
FileAttachment[] attachments = null;
```

you should make an instance of it:

```
FileAttachment[] attachments = new FileAttachment[10];
```

for example

Comment: He does, four lines down inside of his if statement.

Comment: This is totally unrelated. The `attachments` array gets initialized further down and is not part of the `NullReferenceException` thrown.

Comment: I saw that after i posted... my bad